# how to Insert session userid in django database.?

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

I want to Insert session Userid or username in database.

My model.py

```
class Product(models.Model):
{
title = models.CharField(max_length=120)
description = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
userid = session ID
}
```

My View.py

```
    class DealsForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
    model = Product
    fields = ['title','description','userid']
```

Comment: You can choose django countries package, https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-countries#countryselectwidget, here you can overide select option of countries widget.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using FormView to display form, right? Then just override corresponding FormView get_initial method:

```
def get_initial(self):
    initial = super(MyFormView, self).get_initial()
    initial['userid'] = self.request.user.id
    return initial
```